# Chart with different colour for each cell

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, google-visualization

I'm working for my website and I want to create such a chart where each cell of the chart has a different colour as shown in the image below:

[image]

I've searched `Google Charts` and other various javascript based api's for charts but no luck. Any solution is warmly welcome.

Comment: you will have to do something with the div chart is rendering on, like a background image or something..

Comment: Will that be your entire chart, or are you looking for a mixed chart? (Colored cells with another chart on top?)

Comment: @Chloe.. yeah actually, I want these colours as background of chart and data would be displayed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With highcharts, you could do this with [Renderer.rect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) calls.  On the chart complete the below code loops the y and x ticks adding a rectangle in each cell.

```
function (chart) { // on complete

    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
        xTicks = xAxis.tickPositions,
        yTicks = yAxis.tickPositions; // some need vars

    for (var i = 0; i < xTicks.length - 1; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < yTicks.length - 1; j++){ // loop, xTicks and yTicks
            var startX = xAxis.toPixels(xTicks[i]);
            var stopX = xAxis.toPixels(xTicks[i+1]);
            var startY = yAxis.toPixels(yTicks[j+1]);
            var stopY = yAxis.toPixels(yTicks[j]); // determine intersections of ticks

            chart.renderer.rect(startX, startY, stopX-startX,stopY- startY, 0)
            .attr({
                fill: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16), // random color for http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/
                zIndex: 1
            })
            .add(); // place rect for each cell

        }

    }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sa80vofv/).  Produces:

[image]